# How to display few values on the X-axis value on JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Just take a look at this image:
[image: generated graph using JFreeChart]

I have 60 entries on the X-axis, the labels of the values do not fit in the small space so they are shown as "...". Is there a way to somehow hide some of these labels in a way that the entire label of the remaining values are shown?

Comment: Have you tried `setVerticalTickLabels()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the tick units used by the axis by use the axis' `setTickunit()` method.

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setTickUnit-org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit-

Comment: Where exactly do i override this method?

Comment: @MateusViccari you don't need to override the method, just call it on your `NumberAxis` or `DateAxis` instance